# How do I test for the existence of a property in an AngularJS controller using Jasmine?

Tags: angularjs, bdd, jasmine

I have a controllers.js file that looks like this:

```
angular.module('MyApp.controllers', []).

controller('MyCtrl', [function() {

  $scope.type = "default";

}]);
```

and, controllersSpec.js looks like this:

```
describe('controllers', function(){

  beforeEach(module('MyApp.controllers'));

  describe('MyCtrl', function() {

    it('should have a property named "type" whose default value is "default"', inject(function() {

      expect(MyCtrl.type).toBe("default");

    }));

  });

});
```

How can I test that the `MyCtrl` controller has a `type` property and that property's default value is the `"default"` string?

Furthermore, is this type of test even worthwhile or should I rewrite it?  If I should rewrite it, then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are testing a property of your `$scope` and not your Controller function, you need to mock the entire creation of a Ctrl with a mocked `$scope`.

```
var scope, controller;

beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
  scope = $rootScope.$new();
  controller = $controller('MyCtrl', {$scope: scope});
}));

it('should have a default type when created', function() { 
  expect(scope.type).toBe("Default")
});
```